# Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

theres the following statement on the german wikipedia site on Borel sets,

$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Is this oviously?
I mean via embedding $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I could argue the just via different independed generators vor each dimension. But this would state true for discret sets, which is not true?
 Can someone give me a proof of this? Where do I need explicit that $\mathbb{R}$ is not discrete? Thank you.

greetings.

Comment: What you need is that $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable, and hence $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus there is a countable family of open rectangles generating the topology, and this also generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Cf [Product space of Borel Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_measure?wprov=sfsi1) on Wikipedia, including references.